# Adding Prism reference in Xamarin PCL project breaks build on Windows Phone 8.1 and UWP

Tags: nuget, prism, xamarin.forms, portable-class-library

I'm using some of core Prism classes in PCL Project for Multi-platform app. Everything Is fine (I chcecked only on Android as I don't have a Mac) until I add Windows Phone 8.1 or Universal Windows 10 Project and configure them like Xamarin website [tells](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/windows/getting-started/#pcl). What I receive is:

```
Cannot resolve Assembly or Windows Metadata file 'Prism.dll'

Type universe cannot resolve assembly: Prism, Version=6.1.0.0, 
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=91a96d2a154366d8.
```

When I remove all Prism related thing from PCL the projects build, so I'm considering copying prism project into my solution. Or maybe should I reference Prism as a dll instead of nuget or what?

I always thought that nuget takes the job of picking the dll with proper target.

Edit: Xamarin.Froms ver: 2.0.0.6490 (in all projects now) VS 2015.

Comment: are you using the correct package for Forms?  https://www.nuget.org/packages/Prism.Forms/

Comment: Yes, I am. Even though the classes I use are from Core part.
`BindableBase` and `DelegateCommand`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use the current NuGet packages if using UWP because NuGet will add the wrong assemblies to your Xamarin.Forms project. NuGet doesn't know you are using a Xamarin.Forms app and adds the wrong assemblies.  You need to add the references manually.

See this issue:  https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/issues/376